# Change column of DataFrame to set type

Tags: python, pandas, set

I'm having some pandas issue.

I have the following DataFrame:

```
name     random_words
Anne     [hello, hi, bye]
John     [red, blue, green, yellow, grey, black]
Marie    [orange, lemon, pear, apple]
Mark     [cat, dog]
```

I loaded the DataFrame using the `pd.read_csv()` function. The thing is that I need the random_words column to be of type set.

I have tried using `astype()` function but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert values to lists with `strip` and `split` and then to `set`s:

```
print (df)

    name                             random_words
0   Anne                         [hello, hi, bye]
1   John  [red, blue, green, yellow, grey, black]
2  Marie             [orange, lemon, pear, apple]
3   Mark                               [cat, dog]

print (type(df.loc[0,'random_words']))
<class 'str'>

df['random_words'] = df['random_words'].str.strip('[]').str.split(', ').apply(set)
print (df)
    name                             random_words
0   Anne                         {bye, hi, hello}
1   John  {yellow, grey, blue, red, green, black}
2  Marie             {pear, lemon, apple, orange}
3   Mark                               {dog, cat}
```

Or in custom lambda function:

```
df['random_words'] = df['random_words'].apply(lambda x: set(x.strip('[]').split(', ')))
```

If strings have `''` around them (not in sample data, but possible in real data):

```
import ast
df['random_words'] = df['random_words'].apply(lambda x: set(ast.literal_eval(x)))
```

---

If values are lists:

```
print (type(df.loc[0,'random_words']))
<class 'list'>

df['random_words'] = df['random_words'].apply(set)
```

EDIT:

If get this error obviously problem is with missing values:

```
print (df)

    name                             random_words
0   Anne                                      NaN
1   John  [red, blue, green, yellow, grey, black]
2  Marie             [orange, lemon, pear, apple]
3   Mark                               [cat, dog]

df['random_words'] = df['random_words'].str.strip('[]').str.split(', ').apply(set)
print (df)
```

> TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable

Then converting to strings before is possible, but get set with string repr of `NaN` (what should be perfectly OK or not, depends what need):

```
df['random_words'] = df['random_words'].astype(str).str.strip('[]').str.split(', ').apply(set)
print (df)
    name                             random_words
0   Anne                                    {nan}
1   John  {yellow, grey, blue, red, green, black}
2  Marie             {pear, lemon, apple, orange}
3   Mark                               {dog, cat}
```

Comment: Great, what if the words weren't enclosed by []? just: hello,hi,bye

Comment: @HRDSL - then it is simplier `df['random_words'] = df['random_words'].str.split(',').apply(set)`

Comment: @HRDSL - and if lists, more simplier - `df['random_words'] = df['random_words'].apply(set)`

Comment: hmmm that doesn't work. I had to do: df['random_words'].apply(str) at first, and it worked. But now, When I do: df['random_words'].split(',').apply(set), it doesn't work.

Comment: @HRDSL - What is `print (type(df.loc[0,'random_words']))` ?

Comment: it is: <class 'str'>

Comment: @HRDSL - hmmm, it depends of data - if no `astype(str)` there is some error if use my solution?

Comment: I just did: df['random_words'].apply(str) first. Then: df['random_words'].apply(lambda x: x.split(',')).apply(set), and it worked

Comment: @HRDSL - I try explain it in `EDIT` what should be problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"name": ["Anne", "John", "Marie", "Mark"],
              "random_words":[["hello", "hi", "bye"], 
                              ["red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "grey", "black"],
                              ["orange", "lemon", "pear", "apple"],
                              ["cat", "dog"]]})

df['random_words'] = df['random_words'].apply(set)
df

    name    random_words
0   Anne    {hi, bye, hello}
1   John    {blue, yellow, green, black, red, grey}
2   Marie   {orange, pear, apple, lemon}
3   Mark    {cat, dog}
```